# Adding rbenv to my environment

Tags: ruby, rbenv

If I add rbenv to my environment, should I remove RVM from it?

This is my .bash_profile:

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin

export PATH

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cite from https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#installation

> **Compatibility note**: rbenv is incompatible with RVM. Please make sure to fully uninstall RVM and remove any references to it from your shell initialization files before installing rbenv.

So yes, you should remove either RVM or rbenv.